# Updating raster pixel values where they overlap with another raster band

Tags: qgis, raster, update, pixel

I am trying to replace/update the raster pixel values of band '3' of a Land Cover Map to a new value of '24', but only where these pixels overlap with value '4' of another raster layer. How do I write this as an expression in the raster calculator? I am using QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to change value `x` of RasterA-band3, on condition that the RasterB is `4`, then:

```
(RasterA@3 = x) * (RasterB@1 = 4) * 24 +
(RasterA@3 > x) * RasterA@3 +
(RasterA@3 < x) * RasterA@3
```

For instance if your target cell value is `1`,

```
(RasterA@3 = 1) * (RasterB@1 = 4) * 24 +
(RasterA@3 > 1) * RasterA@3 +
(RasterA@3 < 1) * RasterA@3
```